# How to get value from php variable into our javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Actually, I have created a user profile page in which I have added a button to "update info"
as for example:

```
<span id="username"> Username:  <?php echo $username; ?>
<span id="password"> Password:  <?php echo $password; ?>
```

In this page initially I have taken value of username and password using php/mysql commands from database.

Now, I have created a JavaScript file to change innerHTML of id username/password whenever I click "update info", I wanted to add something like as shown bellow:

```
function update()
{

document.getElementById('username').innerHTML=' Username:  <input type="text"    id="uname" name="uname" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">';

 }
```

But I am not getting value of username, I am just getting same php script within input text field.

How to do this in order to get value of "$username" which I was getting directly in main page?

Comment: You echo the password on screen?! Security problem.

Comment: This should work. Is the variable defined when you are using it?

Comment: Even worse: You store your password as plaintext?!

Comment: If you have put that snippet in a JS file, then your server won't interpret it as a PHP file. Also  the whole concept is wrong ...

Comment: Yeah this should work.But i wonder if this actually satisfies your purpose of updating ? shouldn't you be  using ajax or something ?

Comment: leave password field ... just talk about username... I am having problem with username

Comment: Its working when I am not using another file for javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not wrote `<?php ..... ?>` in to your `.js` file. It won't be executed.

It must be in `.PHP` file only or else you can include script file in to your PHP file by `include`, `require`

Answer (score 1):

change it to like.

```
document.getElementById('username').innerHTML=' Username:  <input type="text"    id="uname" name="uname" value="'+<?php echo $username; ?>+'">';
```

Comment: Like @Hamza said, this wont work if the snippet is in a .js file.

Comment: @Mevin Babu you are write this is not working in .js file thank you Mevin.

Answer (score 0):

It can't work, you can't write PHP code in JavaScript files.

You have to print the values inside the php page (.php extension), you can do something like:

```
<script>
 var username = "<?php print $username ?>";
 var password = "<?php print $password ?>";
</script>
```

but be sure you sanitize the PHP values or you expose your users to XSS attacks. **Consider also avoiding to print the password, as rule**. Usually when a user wants to change password he/she must provide the old one before the new.

Comment: Because the scope is window, that is global. Files organization doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="username"> Username:  <?php echo $username; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="usernameHidden" id="usernameHidden" value="<?php echo $username; ?>"/>
<span id="password"> Password:  <?php echo $password; ?>

function update()
{
alert(document.getElementById("usernameHidden").value);
}
```

Comment: My code is already working if I am just putting JavaScript function in same file. So, doing all these stuffs would be worthless.

Comment: ohh..why dont u add that value into session?

Comment: I have lot of things to add that is why I thought using session won't be good. My last option was Ajax.

Comment: @VivekKumar You can not use PHP tags in `.js` file. Please check my answer.